# Windows 10 Mobile (10.0.14393) Background Task for Geofence (LocationTrigger)

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Ever since `10.0.14393` (Anniversery Update), `LocationTrigger` does not seem to work. I have:

- A Windows Phone 8.1 application (also applies to a UWP application).
- A portable library that ouputs to a `Windows Runtime Component` library (`.winmd`)
- A declaration of *Background Task* with *Location* capabilities (set to the library as entry).
- Access with `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync()`
- A `LocationTrigger` of type `Geofence`.

The background task is never triggered. Registration/task code after obtaining access:

```
public sealed class GeofenceTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var taskName = nameof(GeofenceTask);

        foreach (var n in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Where(n => n.Value.Name == taskName))
        {
            n.Value.Unregister(true);
            break;
        }

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder {Name = taskName, TaskEntryPoint = typeof (GeofenceTask).FullName};
        builder.SetTrigger(new LocationTrigger(LocationTriggerType.Geofence));
        builder.Register();
    }

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        // Do magic.
    }
}
```

Running on a Windows Phone 8.1 device or emulator works. Pre-update, it worked on Windows 10 Mobile, too. Is there any known solutions so far?

Comment: Have you checked the sample if there are any differences (and especially if the sample works as expected on your device)? https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Geolocation

Comment: The example also does not work as expected @MZetko (on 10.0.14393)

Comment: We are investigating this issue, thanks for reporting

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having such issue but with simple TimeTrigger task. Task registered without any error, it visible in "Lifecycle Events" of Visual studio, but it not starts at scheduled time. Usually, but not always, helps next steps.

1. Deny access to the app to run in background in Windows settings
2. Restart device
3. Allow access
4. Run app to register tasks

The issue have start happen after update of Universal Windows App development tools to version 1.4.1, but I'm not sure on that point.